# /v1/chains/:chainId/safes/:safeAddress 503 error

Tags: gnosis-safe, bsc, gnosis, safe, gnosis-chain

### Bug description

I am experiencing errors when deploying a safe-wallet-web to support the BSC Testnet locally.
I have already submitted the transaction to BSC Testnet, the API route: The main page of cgw API works but v1/chains/97/safes/address is not working.

I used
[safe-infrastructure Docker](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/blob/main/docs/running_locally.md) to get all the services up and running locally, as did the CGW related services

### Environment

- Browser: Chrome
- Wallet: MetaMask
- Chain: BSC Testnet

### Steps to reproduce

1. Go to the main page.
2. Create a safe account.

### Expected result

The cgw API works.

### Obtained result

### Screenshots

[image: CleanShot 2023-09-17 at 16 11 01@2x]